# Is *p an lvalue or rvalue

Tags: c, lvalue, rvalue

In the following code, is `*a` an rvalue or an lvalue?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int b=2;
    int *a=NULL;
    a=&b;
    *a=3;
    printf("%d",*a);

}
```

Comment: If you can assign to it, it's an lvalue.  Are you asking something more complicated?

Comment: if it's on the right, it's an _r_ value. A donkeybridge as the dutch call it ;)

Comment: +1 good question. It has the subtle point that 1) the same characters referring to the same variables have different meaning. 2) the usual left and right rule doesnt cover the function argument case.

Answer (score 1):

As exposed in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29 :

> Lvalues have memory addresses that are programmatically accessible to the running program (e.g., via some address-of–operator like "&" in C/C++), meaning that they are variables or dereferenced references to a certain memory location. Rvalues can be lvalues (see below) or non-lvalues

So, *a is an lvalue

Answer (score 1):

It is an l-value and can be used in a context of r-value. See the example;

```
int i, j, *p, *q;
p = &i;
q = &j;

*p = 1; // *p is l-value
*q = 2; // *q is l-value

*p = *q // *q is r-value
```

As pointed by [Charles Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19563/charles-bailey) in his comment:- The sub-expression `*q` is still an l-value, **it undergoes an l-value to r-value conversion** because it is used in a context where an r-value is required.

---

Now one may think **Why `*q` is still l-value?**
Because by definition of r-value ***an r-value is a temporary value that does not persist beyond the expression that uses it.***
In this case value of `*q` is persists beyond the expression `*p = *q`.

---

**NOTE:**

> " * " operator--the deference/indirection operator -- operates on pointer variable, and returns an **l-value** equivalent to the value at pointer address.

Comment: The subexpression `*q` is still an lvalue, it undergoes an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion because it is used in a context where an rvalue is required.

Comment: @CharlesBailey; Yes you are right. Actually I was trying to show that one can use an l-value as r-value. Thanks for pointing it.Editing now.

Comment: @charles i would say that subexpression is an rvalue and also an lvalue (which is not a contradiction because the relation from text to value category is not 1:1, because of implicit conversions).. When something initially is an lvalue and appears in that context, it will become an rvalue by reading its value.

Answer (score 1):

According to K&R 2nd edition on p197 §A5:

> ...an lvalue is an expression referring to an object... for example,
>   if `E` is an expression of pointer type, then `*E` is an lvalue
>   expression referring to the object to which `E` points.

additionally Scott Meyers in his book *Effective Modern C++, Introduction - Terminology and Conventions* puts another simpler way to determine lvalue/rvalue:

> A useful heuristic to determine whether an expression is an lvalue is
>   to ask if you can take its address. If you can, it typically is. If
>   you can’t, it’s usually an rvalue. A nice feature of this heuristic is
>   that it helps you remember that the type of an expression is
>   independent of whether the expression is an lvalue or an rvalue.

therefore, when `*p` expression appears on the left side it's a `lvalue`, the right side `rvalue`.